# (JAVAFX) How can I get the 'id' or 'name' of imageview defined in FXML?

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, fxml

I want to get id or name of imageview that defined in FXML.

The id or name of imageview is something like 'img001'.

When I called 'getid()'

```
Imageview tempImg = (ImageView) event.getTarget();
targetNode = new Node();
targetNode.setImage(tempImg.getImage());

System.out.println(targetNode.getId());
```

the result is null.

in FXML,

```
<MyNode id="impo" fx:id="impo" fitHeight="48.0" fitWidth="52.0" focusTraversable="true" 
    layoutX="53.0" layoutY="12.0" onMouseDragged="#addNode" onMousePressed="#addNode" 
    onMouseReleased="#addNode" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <image>
       <Image url="@../../../../../../img/icon_data_add.png" />
    </image>
</MyNode>
```

MyNode is extended from ImageView class.

how can i get the id...?

Comment: How are you binding your `node` with the `controller` ?

Comment: by "fx:controller = myController"

Comment: I am trying to understand how you are accessing it in the controller.. You must be using `@FXML private Node impo` ?

Comment: I have already used it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) might help solve the issue. The most probable problem is `targetNode = new Node();`. You are assigning a new object to `targetNode` and then trying to print `System.out.println(targetNode.getId())`, which, obviously will return `null`

Comment: I can't see imageview in fxml..

Comment: Actually that 'Node' is MyNode Class.
MyNode Class is extended from ImageView

Comment: I modified it. Thank you

Comment: @TaeJaeAquinasLee then get it by `tempImg.getId()`. `targetNode.getId()` will return null by default as ItachiUchiha commented above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new `Node` which is not attached to your FXML.

```
targetNode = new Node(); //Not what you want
```

If your ImageView has an ID defined in your FXML, you can access it with the `getId()` method

```
tempImg.getId();
```

If you want to get the ID of the Node that's wrapping your `ImageView` (`MyNode` in your example), you can call the `getParent()` Method.

```
tempImg.getParent().getId();
```